# Where SQL column value not found in other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've read similar questions and I think I am doing it correct, but I just wanted to make sure my SQL is correct. (Still new to SQL)

I have 2 different tables

```
Students
    id, name, address


Staff
   id, name, address
```

I need to find the total number of students (who are not also staff)

SO I have the following SQL

```
create view nstudents as 
select students.id 
from students 
LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.id = students.id;
```

Then I run the count(*) on the view.

Can someone confirm my SQL is correct or is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `LEFT JOIN` doesn't eliminate students who are also staff, but it could be useful in achieving your goal. `LEFT JOIN` provides you with all results from the left table and matching results from the right table, or `NULL` results if the right table doesn't have a match. If you do this:

```
select count(*) 
from students 
LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.id = students.id
WHERE staff.id IS NULL;
```

I expect you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: but staff.id is never NULL? Do I still need that where condition?

Comment: `staff.id` is never `NULL` in the table, but in the query results, it will be null if there is no `staff.id` which equals `students.id`. That is what `LEFT JOIN` does, and is why you need the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it more natural to do something like this:

```
create view nstudents as 
    select s.id 
    from students s
    where not exists (select 1 from staff st where st.id = s.id) ;
```

This should have the same performance as the `left join`.